# What happens at during the transition of solid to liquid in a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, temperature, induction

So I just watched this video;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i2OVqWo9s0

and I did a little looking through my physics book, and online, but I couldn't find an answer that explained it in simple enough terms for me to understand.

Why does the magnet suddenly drop? I understand that the kinetic energy of the particles inside the magnet increases, therefore the magnet loses its magnetic properties at the moment that all the domains are no longer aligned, due to the particles vibration.

My question is why is it so sudden? and is there a way to work out how long it takes at certain temperatures for certain magnets to lose their magnetic properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason of levitating :**

The high-frequency current of a Cu coil generates the magnetic field. The magnetic field generates an eddy current in the metal body by the electromagnetic induction. The the eddy current by the high-frequency current generates the magnetic field in the metal body. Both magnetic force occurs the magnetic levitation by repelling.

**Reason of heating :**

The induction heating by the the eddy current heats the metal body. And It was melted.

**Reason of dropping :**

"выключаем поле" means "turn off the field". It is shown "turn off the field" in Russian at 03:03 at youtube. By this, the magnetic field disappears. The metal dropped by own mass.

**If the power isn't turned off :**

From the comments on youtube, it was found that the metal is aluminium. If the power isn't turned off, the oxidation of aluminium will be progressed because it's melting. Aluminium (Al) changes to alumina (Al$_2$O$_3$). The melting point of Al and Al$_2$O$_3$ is 660 degrees C and 2072 degrees C, respectively. I think that it is difficult for that apparatus to achieve over 2000 degrees C. So in the long run I think that the metal will drop.